# If(..){include}, includes anyways

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am trying to make a simple Login system for admins. Nothing too special, since it's my first one. I am trying to verify if the `username` and `password` inputted are the same as the one in the database, and then `include` the rest of the page. No errors, everything works as it should, the database access is good, but it's like the `if` statement isn't there. It just `includes` the rest of the page on load.

```
<form action="admin.php" method="POST" class="login">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="username" required>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In">
</form>

<?php
require('connect.php');

$admin = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM admins
SQL;

$username = $_POST['username'];
$pw = $_POST['password'];

$result = $db->query($admin);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    if($username == $row['username'] && $pw == $row['password']){
        include('admininclude.php');
    } else {
        echo 'You are not cool enought to enter. (Username or Password wrong.)';
    }
}

$db->close();
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of looping through all users, you should insert the parameters into the query (use prepared statements for security!). Btw, DO NOT store clear text passwords in a DB! Use hashes and salts.

Comment: Maybe some advice on how to do that? I'm not that good in PHP. This first project is kind of a really simple one.

Comment: What DB class are you using?

Comment: Suggest you check if the form has actually been submitted before doing the SQL query and password check, otherwise a null value for $username will always be equal to a null value for $row['username'], etc.... you're doing this check whether the form has been submitted or whether you're simply displaying the form for the user to login

Comment: @lxg I don't really know what you are talking about, I may look like an idiot now.

Comment: @MarkBaker The form has been submitted.